# How do I avoid repetitive code in this event handler?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have a class Store.

There are multiple stores, eventually hundreds.

I have multiple buttons using one event handler since they all do the same, but with different numbers depending on the store.

I have the event handler detect which button triggered the event.

The variable `store` then stores the store object depending on the button pressed

But the code to detect which button was pressed seems extremely repetitive.

It used to be a lot worse, I shortened it a lot:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source.equals(store01Button)){
        store = store01;
    }else if (source.equals(store02Button)){
        store = store02;
    }else if (source.equals(store03Button)){
        store = store03;
    }else if (source.equals(store04Button)){
        store = store04;
    }else if (source.equals(store05Button)){
        store = store05;
    }else if (source.equals(store05Button)){
        store = store05;
    }
```

I am looking for an answer on how to fix this problem when I have hundreds of stores.

Comment: One simple "opinion": use a Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple "opinion": use a `Map<SomeButtonType, StoreType>` where SomeButtonType is the type of the source, and StoreType is whatever type store is which would reduce your switchboard handler to a one to two lines:

```
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    store = myMap.get(source);
}
```

Of course you would need to fill the map on creation of your buttons, but that should be easy.

Comment: thanks. Its probably the best solution. and that way I can iterate through it if i have to.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the button use `setUserData` to save reference to the store. In the event handler, use `getUserData` to get it. Each of the java fx components maintain a map of properties.

Comment: Thats a great option but since I am using FXML, I dont think there is a way to setUserData in Scene Builder. I could just add it to the FXML or at runtime tho.

Comment: Hmm... Don't you have the button & the store wherever you are creating the map?

Comment: Perhaps FXML is not the best option if you are going to have hundreds of controls... creating that part of the UI with Java (creating the controls in a loop, etc), might be a better way to go.